# Working through Rails3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following when I do `rake routes`

> next_post        /users/next_post/:index(.:format) {:controller=>"users", :action=>"next_post"}

then, when I have this code in my ERB file:

```
<%= link_to "next", :next_post %>
```

I get the following error, and I just can't figure it out

> No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"next_post"}

What am I doing wrong here? The route itself looks like this

```
match '/users/next_post/:index', 
        :controller => "users", 
        :action => 'next_post', 
        :as => :next_post
```

Comment: what's that `:index` parameter for?

Comment: I'm passing in the index of the post that I want returned. As an example, you're on the 4th post, and you want to go forward. I would pass in 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this

```
<%= link_to "next", next_post_path(@post.id + 1) %>
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I was just ignorant as to how to pass in the index properly.